# How to retrieve the rows which are selected in the list report page of smart templates

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

This is the List Report type of Smart Template application
[image]

Here I have selected 2nd and 5th row, I also have a button named Send Requests in the section part which is highlighted. If I click this button it calls a javascript controller function which is defined in the extensions of the application. In this js function how can I retrieve the selected rows that are selected?

I have enabled the checkboxes in this page by mentioning this code

"settings": { "gridTable": false, "multiSelect": true } in the manifest.json

As it was recommended by this link https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/116b5d82e8c545e2a56e1b51b8b0a9bd.html

I want to know how can I retrieve the rows which got selected?

Answer (score 2):

There is an API that you can use for your use case. It is described here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bd2994b69ef542998becbc69ab093f7e.html

Basically, you just need to call the [getSelectedContexts](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.extensionAPI.ExtensionAPI.html#getSelectedContexts) method. Unfortunately you will not be able to really get the items themselves, only the binding contexts (which point to the data entities which are selected). Excerpt from the documentation:

> After you have defined a view extension, you can access and modify the
>   properties of all UI elements defined within these extensions (for
>   example, change the visibility). **However, you cannot access any UI
>   elements that are not defined within your view extensions.**

Answer (score 2):

> In this type of table there is way.

```
var myTable=sap.ui.getCore().byId("your table id");
```

get all rows:

```
var myTableRows=myTable.getRows();
```

now get selected Indices

```
var selectedIndeices=myTable.getSelectedIndices(); //this will give you array of indeices.
```

now run loop on indeices array. And get particular row item;
// get binding path

```
 var bindingpath=myTableRows[2].getBindingContext().sPath; // this will return eg:"/ProductCollection/2"
```

// now get Binding object of that particular row.

```
var myData=myTableRows[2].getModel().getObject(bindingpath); // this will return binding object at that perticular row.
```

// once your loop is over in the end you will have all object of selected row. then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: I am using a smart templates. Where can I get the table Id?

Comment: you may have given id to your table just use that. If not then give one.

Answer (score 1):

If you use smart template create an extension.

This is the standard event befor the table is rebinding:

```
onBeforeRebindTableExtension: function (oEvent) {
            this._table = oEvent.getSource().getTable();
        }
```

In your action function (or where you want) call the table and get the context :

```
this._table.getSelectedContexts();
```